# configargparse: Any way to check multiple values to single argument from within configargparse?

Tags: python

I'm using [ConfigArgParse](https://pypi.org/project/ConfigArgParse/) in Python to parse command line arguments.  One argument in particular should take two numeric values: the first value should be larger than the second, neither should be negative, and the second should not be zero.  I had originally thought that a checker function passed as the `type` for the `ArgumentParser.add_argument` function to add the argument would work, but then realized that `type` operated on each value given to the argument individually, rather than in a group.

How can I do this from within `configargparse` itself?  It's easy enough to write a function to check this after the fact, but this argument is likely to be used in multiple places in code, so it would be nice if it could check itself instead of having something from the outside do it.

In this sample code, the `arg_checker` function is what I would like to pass as a `type` to the `add_argument` function, assuming both numbers are passed as a single string to the function.  Since this is not the case when used on actually command lines, the examples that follow of what should be good and bad arguments have the two numbers separated into two separate strings to mimic the real behavior.  Also, since these are numeric values intended to be passed in as such, I don't regard requiring that the two numbers be passed in the command line as a string, like `python script.py -a "2 3"` as a good solution.

```
import configargparse

def arg_checker(arg: str):

    # Double-check only two arguments via assert.
    splitted = arg.split()
    assert len(splitted) == 2, "Did not have only two values."

    first = float(splitted[0])
    second = float(splitted[1])
    if first < 0:
        raise ValueError("First is negative")
    if second <= 0:
        raise ValueError("Second is negative or zero")
    if first > second:
        raise ValueError("First must be less than second.")
    return (first, second)

parser = configargparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-a', nargs=2, type=float)  # type=arg_checker)

# Good
parser.parse_args(['-a', '2', '3'])

# All bad
parser.parse_args(['-a', '3', '2'])
parser.parse_args(['-a', '-1', '3'])
```

Comment: Just to confirm, do you mean [this](https://pypi.org/project/ConfigArgParse/)? (`configargparse` is not a standard library.)

Comment: @chepner Yes that's what I mean.